# Infinite scroll flatlist with request failed status code error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, use-effect

I want to load more data(which I am fetching from an API) when I scroll my app, which worked but I keep getting the below error.

**[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Request failed with status code 429]**

**Possile Unhandled Promise Rejection (id:90)**

**Error: Request failed with status code 429**

**Error: Request failed with status code 429**

Most of time the error above show up when, the data is loading more and I click to another screen or I refresh the screen below is my code.

```
    const UserList = ( {navigation, route} ) => {
    const { userlist } = route.params;
      
    const [userData, setUser] = useState([]);
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

    const getData = () => {
        setIsLoading(true)
        axios.get(hosturl.loaduser + userlist.user_id + '&page=' +currentPage)
        .then((response) => {
            setEvent([...userData, ...response.data.data])
            setIsLoading(false)
        })
    }
  
    useEffect(() => {    
        getData();
    }, [currentPage]);

    const renderItem = ({item}) => {
        return(
            <Text>{item.user_name}</Text>
            <Text>{item.user_type}</Text>
            <Text>{item.user_address}</Text>
        )
    }

    const renderLoader = () => {
        return (
            isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#aaa" /> : null
        )
    }

    const LoadMoreItem = () => {
        setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1);
    }   

    return (
    <FlatList 
            data = {userData}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
            renderItem={renderItem}
            ListFooterComponent = {renderLoader}
            onEndReached={LoadMoreItem}
            onEndReachedThreshold={0}
    />
    )
  
  export default UserList
```

Thank for the help

Answer (score 0):

Two problems here: A. the status code 4XX on the response indicates that there's something in your request that the API is rejecting, B. You're not catching any errors from your API in your axios call which can be done using the `.catch(er => console.log(er))`, which is causing the error to go unhandled.

To provide additional help, it would be useful to know what your API end of this whole deal looks like, to see why the call is being rejected. That or you could reference the network panel of your devtools and see what response was provided by the API in addition to the status code (if any).

Status code reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status

After cross-referencing your status code against this list, it seems that you're initiating too many API calls and some sort of throttling on your API is preventing you from issuing more calls.

Comment: Hi @methodical thanks for the respond, I will add the `.catch(er => console.log(er))` and  this is the content `https://placewave.com/avatar/` of the `hosturl`